# Question about Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

> How to compute $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_0^{\infty}\Big(1+\frac{x}{n}\Big)^{-n}\sin\Big(\frac{x}{n}\Big) dx$$

I want to use the Dominated Convergence Theorem. so it becomes $$\int_0^{\infty}\lim_{n\to \infty}\Big(1+\frac{x}{n}\Big)^{\frac{n}{x}(-x)}\sin\Big(\frac{x}{n}\Big) dx=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x}\times 0 dx=0$$

I have trouble finding the dominating term, which is essential for me to apply dominated convergence theorem.

Could anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: Try using [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula).

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148529/computing-lim-limits-n-to-infty-int-0-infty-frac-sinx-n1x-nn/151316#151316

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the Bernoulli inequality we have:
$$ \left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{-n}\leq e^{-x}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)\tag{1}$$
and:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-x}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)\sin\frac{x}{n}\,dx &=& n \int_{0}^{+\infty}(1+x)\,\sin(x)\, e^{-nx}\,dx\\ &\leq& n\int_{0}^{+\infty}(1+x)\,e^{-nx}\,dx\\&=&1+\frac{1}{n}\tag{2}\end{eqnarray*} $$
So the dominated convergence theorem applies. In fact, 
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}(1+x)\,\sin(x)\,e^{-nx}\,dx = \left(\frac{n+1}{n^2+1}\right)^2\leq\frac{1}{(n-1)^2}\tag{3}$$
so we don't even need the dominated convergence theorem to prove that the limit is zero.

Answer (score 3):

The sine is clearly bounded by 1, so it suffices to show that
$$ \left( 1+\frac{x}{n} \right)^{-n} \leqslant \frac{1}{(1+x/2)^2}, $$
which is clearly integrable. How do you do that? In fact, you can do it in the same way that G.H. Hardy shows in *A Course in Pure Mathematics* that $(1+1/n)^n$ is increasing in $n$ (viz., that the size of each term increases, and the number of terms also increases). In a similar manner, the sequence $(1+x/n)^{-n}$ can be shown to be decreasing, and hence you immediately conclude that it is bounded by the second term, $(1+x/2)^{-2}$.

Comment: why $\frac{1}{1+x}$ is integrable?

Comment: @Sherry Oh right, brain fart. But we'll all agree that $(1+x/2)^{-2}$ is integrable, right?